# ASP.Net MVC 3.0 C# How to find if a property Exists?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

Hi i would like to check if a property exists?

This is my code

```
 string abpath=null;
    var hc= HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer;
    if (hc.AbsolutePath !=null)
    {
        var _temp = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath;
        abpath = _temp.ToString();
    }
```

I would like to Find out if **AbsolutePath** exists

can any one help me how to check.
right now it throws error as AbsolutePath doesn't exists to check

Thanks for your time

Comment: So really you need to check if HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer is not null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to map the absolute path (url) to a local file system path. Then you can check whether the file exists:

```
var localPath = Server.MapPath(hc.AbsolutePath);
var exists = System.IO.File.Exists(localPath);
```

**Update:**
I guess I misunderstood the question. The problem is, that if your page/action/etc is called directly (e.g. by entering its URL in the browser), then there is no Referrer (previous page). So you have to first check `Request.UrlReferrer` for null:

```
if (hc != null && hc.AbsolutePath != null)
{
  // ...
}
```

**BTW**: since AbsolutePath is already a string, there is no need to call `ToString()`on it. So you can simplify your code some more:

```
if (hc != null)
{
  abpath = hc.AbsolutePath;
}
```

Comment: That's my problem it throws error at var localPath = Server.MapPath(hc.AbsolutePath); says Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Check for url referrer first.
So try using code as below,

```
 string abpath=null;
    var hc= HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer;
    if (hc !=null && !string.isNullOrEmpty(hc.AbsolutePath))
    {
        var _temp = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath;
        abpath = _temp.ToString();
    }
```